# how to use variables in SQL statement (MS Access)

Tags: sql, variables, ms-access

How can I declare a variable that contain the following function:

DSUM function

and put this variable in SQL statement like that :-

```
update Tbl-1
set [Field1] = (the variable that I want to declare)
where ...
  and etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare? Anyway, you can pull a value with `DSum`:

```
update Tbl-1
set [Field1] = DSum("[Amount]", "SomeOtherTable", "[SomeField] = SomeValue")
```

Answer (score 0):

The type of logic that you can apply is not possible, a variable that store a function? I only know the case of <> in C#, but your case is totally different.

If you read the next article you will find an easy explanation: http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/domain/dsum.php

Then you should incorporate in the Set part directly the operation that you need, in this case:

update Tbl-1
set [Field1] = (The operation that you want to apply on the Field1)
where ...
  and etc.